# Nant on Windows Vista 64

Tags: nant

I was wondering if anyone has successfully ran Nant on Windows Vista 64 bit version. It keeps failing with

set-props:

[sysinfo] Setting system information properties under sys.*

BUILD FAILED

Property name 'sys.env.CommonProgramFiles(x86)' is invalid.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have run nant scripts under vista64. But maybe you can create a very small script which fails, and show it here, so we can answer why it does not run.

Comment: Repro steps:
1. use NAnt 0.85 to build the attached file under x64 
Windows.
2. Note error message: "Property 
name 'sys.env.CommonProgramFiles(x86)' is invalid." http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=402868&aid=1213185&group_id=31650 and a hack from Google Groups - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ccnet-user/iNwDd1Rheqs

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it works. NAnt is by default built for 32-bit. Therefore, one has to remember to run this in a 32-bit command prompt or [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx). I run NAnt scripts out of PowerShell (x86) mode on a Vista 64 machine, but an SDK prompt (32-bit) would works as well.

Answer (score 2):

It also has worked well for me.  I do run as Scott said in a 32bit command prompt.

It could also be just a specific thing you are trying to capture that nAnt is not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using NAnt on my Windows 7 64 bit environment, and have found that in order to do so (without needing to use a 32bit command environment) is to simply remove the reference in your NAnt scripts to sysinfo.

I have been through our build scripts over and over and cannot see any downside to removing this setting, as I cannot prove that I'm using the result of it anyway, other than to dump lots of data to the screen which is invaluable during debugging!!

Hope this helps!